# NetSuite Advanced PDF/HTML Template: How to remove first line from free-format text field

Tags: html, netsuite, freemarker

I was wondering if anyone can assist on how to do this?

Custom field: ${check.custbodysubsidiaryaddress} (Free-format text field)

Actual Output:

Sarah Sheppard

221 Lakeshore Drive

Barrie, ON M6B4B7

Expected Output:

221 Lakeshore Drive

Barrie, ON M6B4B7

Note: this is not a real name/address just an example

I tried the  but I am really not sure how to correctly use this

Comment: Hi, may I know why you are using a custom body field for the subsidiary address? Advanced PDF/HTML Templates in NetSuite gives you access to the subsidiary information. You can access the subsidiary's address by using ${subsidiary.mainaddress_text}